# How do i detect if a particular tcp stream connected through boost::asio_stream_async is closed?

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost, tcp

My `C++ library` is making tcp connection with a list of  using boost::asio_connector_async 
The issue is that if one of the streams is closed due to some reason, no information is sent by boost to my library regarding the same.
Hence, my library is never able to detect which streams are closed and which are still open.
My library contains an object of class boost::asio_connector_async (by the name of connector) and connects to the host, port in this way:

```
connector.async_connect(hostname.c_str(), qport.c_str(),          boost::bind(bc::asio_bind_sock_chan<pubsub_channel,pubsub_channel::text_marshaler_registry>(),boost::ref(chan), boost::ref(mar_reg), hostname, qport, channel_logger, _1, _2, _3));
```

When a particular `<host,port>` stream is closed, the function `boost::asio_connector_async::on_stream_closed` is called internally from the file `asio_stream_async.hpp`

```
void on_stream_closed(void * sp, const std::string & host, const std::string port) {
        boost::channel::logger_stream(logger_) << "boost::channel::asio_connector_async::on_stream_closed - " << host << ":" << port << ": stream 0x" << sp << " closed";
      }
```

I want to attach my library to `boost::asio_connector_async::on_stream_closed` in such a  way that whenever this particular function is called, some function in my library is also invoked so that my library is aware which particular stream is closed and then should try reconnecting with that stream
Please suggest how can I achieve the same? I cannot think of anyway to achieve this without modifying boost library (which I am not supposed to do)
If there is some other way to detect closed connections, please suggest me those too.

I am new in this sort of network programming, hence require help with the same.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Client disconnects needs to be handled in your `handle_read` callback (or whatever name you have provided).

The async read callback will get called with `0` bytes read from stream. OR you can check the system error code as well for `asio::error::connection_reset` or `asio::error::eof` OR just simply `bytes_read == 0` (I would recommend to do other mentioned tests as well.)

An example (from asio examples: chat_client.cpp)

```
asio::async_connect(socket_, endpoints,
        [this](std::error_code ec, tcp::endpoint)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read_header();
          }
         //ATTN: This is where you should handle failed socket connection
        });

void do_read_header()
  {
    asio::async_read(socket_,
        asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
        [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec && read_msg_.decode_header())
          {
            do_read_body();
          }
          else
          {
            socket_.close();
          }
        });
  }
```

Look for the `ATTN` comment in `async_connect` handler.

Comment: I dont think boost/channel/streams/asio_connector_async.hpp::async_conect takes an "error" argument.
      void async_connect(std::string host, std::string port,
                         sock_conn_handler hndl) 
My code is directly calling async_connect using an object of asio_connector_sync

Comment: My basic concern is to send the disconnection information to the client library. Boost library detects the disconnection when the socket is closed but that info is not communicated with the client library.

Comment: @ShubhiAgarwal Its your handler which should take `asio::error`, not async_connect. In your case `sock_conn_handler `. Can you tell me the signature of the function `sock_conn_handler ` ?

Comment: sock_conn_handler is also defined in boost lib and not my code. See boost code below:
 //async_connect
 template<typename sock_conn_handler>
 void async_connect(std::string host, std::string port,sock_conn_handler hndl) {..... boost::shared_ptr<conn_handler_base> handler(new conn_handler<sock_conn_handler> (hndl));
        sock->async_connect(.....)); }

conn_handler is a class defined in boost::asio_connector_async.hpp

Comment: Call to async_connect looks like this
        connector.async_connect(
            hostname.c_str(), qport.c_str(),
            boost::bind(bc::asio_bind_sock_chan<pubsub_channel, pubsub_channel::text_marshaler_registry>(),
                        boost::ref(chan), boost::ref(mar_reg), hostname, qport, channel_logger, _1, _2, _3)
            );

Comment: @ShubhiAgarwal Weird, I am not able to find `asio_connector_async` anywhere in the asio source. Can you tell me where `asio_connector_async` is declared ?

Answer (score 0):

Any call made by asio will complete with an error if connection failure is detected.

That however does not mean the remote end will remain reachable. TCP send completes as soon as the data gets put on the kernel queue. Detection of failure can takeca long time to be detected.

If connection fidelity is important you will need to design an echo request into your session layer protocol.

Comment: Is there a more straight forward way to to do this without modifying at protocol level?

Comment: @ShubhiAgarwal This would happen only if the endpoint is not able to send a `RST` TCP packet. Usually when the endpoint server machine crashes or sudden power off or whatever other reason. You can instead use `asio::socket_base::keep_alive ` which sends probe packets after every configurable timeout. If it detects a broken pipe, you will get the read handler called again with the error set as I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The socket will also error if the local link layer is disconnected (ethernet cable yanked out). What you will not be notified of is if the remote ethernet cable is yanked out or if an intermediate router dies.

Comment: Thank you guys. I have some questions regarding keepalive:
1. Would this option be set on every socket connection I make from the client(for every host,port)?
2. socket is getting created in the boost library itself. I am passing ioservice to boost, and there the socket is getting created. How do I set keepalive in this case when I do not have access to the socket object?